# Google Sign In - Check if the user belongs to a specific organisation

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-signin

I'm trying to check if a sign in user belongs to a specific organisation.

By organisation, I mean a GSuite organisation. For example, the company I work for is XYZ, I want to see if user X is within that organisation.

I've followed the docs on [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) which work a charm for retrieving basic user details.

Here's where I'm up to:

```html
<head>
  <title>Pricing</title>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<Client ID>">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
  <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  <script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
      var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());

      /*
        At this point, I want to check if the user belongs to a specific GSuite organisation
      */
    }

    function signOut() {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      auth2.signOut().then(function() {
        console.log('User signed out.');
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `Here's where I'm up to` - where are you checking for membership of GSuite organisation? looks like you just have a comment, which wont actually do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to just query the user email and then check the domain of that email address.

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}
```